# Не могу кликнуть на ссылку Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Нужно чтобы система нажала на определенную кнопку (Сервис) на сайте. Но у меня не получается, там просто нет Button и я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы система кликнула.

```
link_service = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='app/service']")
link_service.click()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через CSS селектор тоже пробовал, не получается.
Iframe нету.
Помогите плиз
Вот полный код:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\stepick\\chromedriver.exe'


chrome_service = Service(driver_path)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get('https://rus-erp.ru/')


username_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='tel']")
username_field.send_keys('Логин')


password_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password']")
password_field.send_keys('Пароль')

button_login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary']")
button_login.click()
```

Comment: Это я нечаянно добавил
link_service = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR"//li(@class'bx_catalog_text_title')".find.By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href,'/warehouse/?visible=all')]") link_service.click() time.sleep(2)

Comment: Без авторизации проверить не могу, найдите доступный пример на котором можно протестировать и я попытаюсь вам помочь.